# Do email pattern check for md-chips tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to check email pattern to Angular-Material `md-chips` tag given below, `type="email"` not working.

```
<md-chips ng-model="ctrl.emails" md-separator-keys="ctrl.customKeys" type="email" ></md-chips>
```

Comment: Not sure to understand. `type` is not an attribute of `md-chips`

Comment: So, How can i archive email validation in md-chips any Idea?

Comment: With a regex check for example: `/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`